# Using micropython on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, pi-pico, micropython

I have found a library and sample code that seems to work very well on the Pico W, but I need a bit more power, so I'd like to use the same library on the Pi Zero W instead. Initially, I tried using the code as-is, but I immediately get errors because required modules (utime for example) are not available.

Is there any simple solution for using micropython on Pi Zero W? Or do I just need to debug and edit it to until it works?

I've spent too long trying to find an equivalent library - some come close, but they don't have everything I need.

Thanks

Comment: WHY?? Raspberry Pi OS already includes python. Micropython is just a subset. Your real problem will occur with libraries - the hardware on Pico is not the same as Pi.

Answer (score 1):

From the [looks of things](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/gettingstarted.html), there is a Unix port that should work ("...is a version of MicroPython that runs on Linux, macOS, and other Unix-like operating systems").  However, it isn't in the RpiOS apt repo, so you will have to [build it from source](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/gettingstarted.html#building-the-unix-port-of-micropython).

Installing the required dependencies will be the same as it is on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev git pkg-config
```

To get the source code you will need `git` (which is included in the line above):

```
> cd /usr/local/src
> sudo git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/micropython/micropython.git
```

If you don't want to put it in `/usr/local/src`, use whatever directory you like; you also don't have to download or build it via `sudo` if you put it somewhere your regular user has write permissions.

The `ports/unix` directory mentioned in the build directions will be in the git repo directory.  If you downloaded with `sudo git`, you'll have to `sudo make` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full implementation

https://github.com/boochow/micropython-raspberrypi

Here's a list of what's supported

https://github.com/boochow/micropython-raspberrypi/wiki/Quick-reference-for-the-Raspberry-Pi-Zero---W-MicroPython